# How to select a row without using OnSelectedIndexchanged in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In an ASP.NET GridView control

- Is it possible to select a row without using the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event?

  e.g. suppose I want to have a custom button on the GridView called "ProcessThis" for every row in the grid, and I want an `OnClick` method to then access the selected row values.
- If that is not possible, is it then possible to alter the text and position of the select button generated by `OnSelectedIndexChanged`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add a custom button to the `GridView` whose `CommandName` property is `Select`.  Then use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event as usual.

Why do you say you don't want the `SelectedIndexChanged` event to fire?  Note that this event will fire even if you change the selected index in code by calling the `GridView.SelectRow` method.

Comment: thanx joe.but that does not work because the selectedrow is still null hence an exception gets thrown

Comment: sorry. it works. i forgot to remove "onrowcommand" before testing. thanx for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes it is possible to select a row without using the
>   OnSelectedIndexChanged event.

You have to use [RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) event of `GridView` like

**C#**

```
    protected void Gridview1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "ProcessThis")
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                GridViewRow row = Gridview1.Rows[index];
                // Do what ever you want....
            }
    }
```

**.aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        onrowcommand="Gridview1_RowCommand">
                        <Columns>
                        <asp:ButtonField Text="Process This" CommandName="ProcessThis" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

You have to assign `CommandName` in the button that you are using inside your `GridView`.

Hope you understand and works for you.

Comment: You're just repeating what I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`RowCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) event on the gridview for that purpose. It is triggered every time a button is clicked in the gridview.

If you use the [`DataKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys.aspx) property in your markup you can fetch a specific ID for instance from the row of the button, in order to process a specific row. Examples are available in the docs.

Comment: thanx patrick. but that does not get the selectedrow, because when i try to gets the row's index as in "..if e.CommandName.ToLower() == "select") { GridViewRow row = Mygrid.SelectedRow;
                    int index = row.RowIndex;} i get an exception because the selected row is null...

Comment: But you you wanted to process the data related to the row. If you look at the example in the docs you'll see how you get the data related to the row, and then you can process it. If you want to act on the data after it is **selected**, use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.